# Simulates repeated rolls of a pair of dice until 100 rolls of r have been obtained; the number of rolls is then printed

Tags: python, while-loop, probability, dice

I'm trying to count how many rolls it takes to get 100 rolls of a sum of two dice, r (2-12) and prints it. This is what I've tried so far:

```
from random import randrange
def diceprob(r):
    count = 0

    while count < 100:
        roll = random.randrange(2, 13)
        if roll == r:
            count += 1
    print("It took {} rolls to get 100 rolls of {}".format(count, r))
```

But when ran, it always prints out, "It took 100 rolls to get 100 rolls of 5", with the value of of 5 changing based on what r is called as. Why isn't the count being incremented properly?

Comment: The sum of two dice rolls is not properly presented by `random.randrange(2, 13)`. The sums in such a roll are no distributed evenly. For example there is one combination creating a 2 and six summing up to 7.

Comment: Take a look at probability distribution of  the sum of two dices http://mathinsight.org/image/two_dice_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were counting rolls that got `r` as the result, not all rolls.
Also note that distribution of the sum of two six-sided dice rolls is not uniform therefore you need to call `random.randrange(1, 7)` twice

```
import random
def diceprob(r):
    total_count = 0
    count = 0

    while count < 100:
        roll = random.randrange(1, 7) + random.randrange(1, 7)
        total_count += 1
        if roll == r:
            count += 1
    print("It took {} rolls to get 100 rolls of {}".format(total_count, r))
```

If we invoke `diceprob` for various values of `r` we will get results

```
It took 3849 rolls to get 100 rolls of 2
It took 1932 rolls to get 100 rolls of 3
It took 1394 rolls to get 100 rolls of 4
It took 881 rolls to get 100 rolls of 5
It took 717 rolls to get 100 rolls of 6
It took 537 rolls to get 100 rolls of 7
It took 748 rolls to get 100 rolls of 8
It took 798 rolls to get 100 rolls of 9
It took 1295 rolls to get 100 rolls of 10
It took 1881 rolls to get 100 rolls of 11
It took 3689 rolls to get 100 rolls of 12
```

Compare it with graph of [the distribution](http://mathinsight.org/image/two_dice_distribution)

Comment: Would there be any error or miss calculation if I do randrange(2,13)?

Comment: @Frank yes. `randrange(2,13)` has [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(discrete)), but the sum of two two dices has another distribution. See http://mathinsight.org/image/two_dice_distribution

Answer (score 0):

You need two variables, one for the total rolls, and another for the rolls that equal `r`. You're only counting the rolls that equal `r`, and just printing that.

```
def diceprob(r):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    while count < 100:
        roll = random.randrange(2, 13)
        total++
        if roll == r:
            count++
    print("It took {} rolls to get {} rolls of {}".format(total, count, r))
```

There's a separate problem that you're rolling one 11-sided die (with numbers from 2 to 12), not two 6-sided dice.